# why is my user detail not saving into realtime database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a flutter web app. The code for sign-in and login works fine but the data are not saving into my real-time database. This code works fine for the android app and saving user details on firebase. What is wrong with it?

**email_signin.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_project/UserHome.dart';

class EmailSignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EmailSignUpState createState() => _EmailSignUpState();
}

class _EmailSignUpState extends State<EmailSignUp> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  DatabaseReference dbRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Users");
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Sign Up")),
        body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter User Name",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter User Name';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Email",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter an Email Address';
                    } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: ageController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Age",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Age';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Password",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Password';
                    } else if (value.length < 6) {
                      return 'Password must be atleast 6 characters!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: isLoading
                    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                    : ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                Colors.lightBlue)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = false;
                            });
                            registerToFb();
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
              )
            ]))));
  }

  void registerToFb() {
    firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((result) {
      dbRef.child(result.user.uid).set({
        "email": emailController.text,
        "age": ageController.text,
        "name": nameController.text
      }).then((res) {
        isLoading = false;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => UserHome(uid: result.user.uid)),
        );
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    nameController.dispose();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    ageController.dispose();
  }
}

class FirebaseFirestore {
  static var instance;
}
```

**email_login.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_project/UserHome.dart';

class EmailLogIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EmailLogInState createState() => _EmailLogInState();
}

class _EmailLogInState extends State<EmailLogIn> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  bool isLoading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Login")),
        body: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Email Address",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Email Address';
                    } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid email address!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Enter Password",
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Enter Password';
                    } else if (value.length < 6) {
                      return 'Password must be atleast 6 characters!';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: isLoading
                    ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                    : ElevatedButton(
                        style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                Colors.lightBlue)),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            setState(() {
                              isLoading = true;
                            });
                            logInToFb();
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text('Submit'),
                      ),
              )
            ]))));
  }

  void logInToFb() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((result) {
      isLoading = false;
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserHome(uid: result.user.uid)),
      );
    }).catchError((err) {
      print(err.message);
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error"),
              content: Text(err.message),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });
  }
}
```

**userhomepage.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:new_project/widgets/all_pro.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class UserHome extends StatefulWidget {
  String uid;
  String userEmail;
  UserHome({this.uid, this.userEmail});
  @override
  _UserHomeState createState() => _UserHomeState();
}

class _UserHomeState extends State<UserHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xffa58faa),
        ),
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountEmail: FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                        .reference()
                        .child("Users")
                        .child(widget.uid)
                        .once(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Text(snapshot.data.value['email']);
                      } else {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    }),
                accountName: FutureBuilder(
                    future: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                        .reference()
                        .child("Users")
                        .child(widget.uid)
                        .once(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Text(snapshot.data.value['name']);
                      } else {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    }),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFf38181),
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: () => null,
                ),
                title: Text('Home'),
                onTap: () {
                  print(widget.uid);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: new IconButton(
                  icon: new Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: () => null,
                ),
                title: Text('Settings'),
                onTap: () {
                  print(widget.uid);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(height: 300, child: AllProducts()),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: As you can see the nav drawer much fetch the username and email of the user but it is not.]
The authentication works fine but my problem is with the data not going into the realtime database. It is always showing null.

Comment: does your database contains the data?

Comment: I can see the user in authentication page but not in realtime database.

Comment: yes so if you don't have anything in the db then how will it show the data. I think thats the problem. authentication won't create the db

Comment: Did you already step through the code in a debugger? The `dbRef.child(result.user.uid).set({...})` looks fine at first glance, but if you run in a debugger, you can check that and see if it then reaches the `then` callback.